# Writing a modification for multiple versions of the original application

Tags: java, version

I am writing a modification for a specific version of a Java application. I modify the existing code and add my own special code into it.

Now, when the original Java application gets an update with major codebase changes and I would like my modification to be available for that new version, it would be really hard and time consuming for me to copy all of my own code and update all changes that I made to the original source code. When I code a new feature, I will then have to copy the whole feature for multiple versions of the original application.

My goal is to support multiple versions simultaneously, but I am wondering if there is a simpler (or more efficient) way of doing this so I keep my own code in a common location and only adapt some other parts of the code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems to me the original developers of the code won't know about the hooks you added to use your code.   So when they update their version of the code, it will no longer know how to use your addition.  And other thing could change too.  All this assuming I understand the situation.

Comment: Is this a commercial application that is covered under copyright laws? In which case, in some countries what you are doing is illegal and it could be considered malicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple solution.

You forked an application, the original developers know nothing of your fork, and regardless, even if they did they are not required to do anything to maintain compatibility.

If your fork potentially has value to others, you should lobby to contribute it to the original project, and become a contributor on that project.  Otherwise, it will be up to you to diff every new version of the base against the previous version and then adjust your code to deal with any incompatibilities introduced by the new version.